# Is it possible to sort Data Frame by a value in the row before?

Tags: r

I want to sort a data frame by the value in the row before. That's why
I have two columns "startpoint" and "endpoint".
Now I want to sort the rows so that each row with a certain "endpoint" is followed by the row with the same value in "startpoint".

for example:

```
+------------+-----------+
| Startpoint | Endpoint  |
+------------+-----------+
| Berlin     | Munich    |
| Munich     | Paris     |
| Paris      | Barcelona |
| Barcelona  | Rom       |
+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: If you are looking for an answer with more detail than "*Yes, it is possible*", please share a reproducible example (copy/pasteable in valid R syntax!!), that is not already sorted how you want. Also, if applicable, please mention if you know that there is already a unique solution. (E.g., are all the start and endpoints unique? Is every startpoint except the first guaranteed to have a corresponding endpoint in another row?)

Comment: I think this depends on whether the rows between them constitute a complete journey without gaps or branches or loops. Non trivial.

Comment: Try the following once your (identical?) columns are both in alphabetical order, this should just shift everything up one row in the second column, and move the first entry to the end (you might want that to be an NA, impossible to tell from your information): `df[1:(length(df[,1])-1), 2] <- df[c(2:length(df[,1]), 1), 2]`

Comment: how many rows can this go to?

Comment: additionally, is there any time variable associated with these trips? sorting by that would seem to be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit conflicted about giving an answer to op's that don't follow posting guidelines, but I found this to be an interesting puzzle to solve.

Provided there is no conflicts such as having multiple flights (I presume they are flights) with the same place of departure (or of destination), or having a series that goes "round trip", in which cases you'll run into infinite looping, here's a (somewhat surpisingly simple) solution.

```
flights <- read.table(sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, text = "
dep,arr
Montreal,Washington
Berlin,Munich
Miami,Paris
Munich,New York
Barcelona,Rome
New York,Montreal
Washington,Miami
Paris,Barcelona
")       

cont <- TRUE

while (cont) {
  # move down a flight for which the dep is an arr further down
  for (i in 1:(nrow(flights)-1)) {
    ind <- which(flights$arr == flights$dep[i])
    if (length(ind) == 0)  next
    if (ind > i) {
      flights <- flights[c(seq_len(i-1),
                           (i+1):ind,
                           i,
                           seq(from = ind + 1,
                               length.out = nrow(flights) - ind)),]
      break
    }
    cont <- FALSE
  }
}
```

### Results

```
> flights
         dep        arr
2     Berlin     Munich
4     Munich   New York
6   New York   Montreal
1   Montreal Washington
7 Washington      Miami
3      Miami      Paris
8      Paris  Barcelona
5  Barcelona       Rome
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very convoluted first solution that I welcome attempts to improve, since I don't know much about sort algorithms. I think this also won't work for any large table because `permutations` increases in size too rapidly (it's the factorial, after all).

I start by making a reordered version with some value column, since presumably that's why we have to rearrange the rows. First get the list of all the potential row orders. Then do a check on the rows to see if the next `start` is equal to the current `end`, and if so keep those rows together. Filter out the row orders that don't have those rows together, and then randomly shuffle the table to one of the remaining row orders. Stop when there's only one option left.

This clearly assumes that there is a unique solution (really there are at least two since you could just reverse this order and satisfy the condition but early on one will randomly be chosen).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(arrangements)
set.seed(100)
tbl <- tibble(
  start = c("Berlin", "Munich", "Paris", "Barcelona"),
  end = c("Munich", "Paris", "Barcelona", "Rome"),
  val = rnorm(4)
) %>%
  slice(sample(1:nrow(.), nrow(.))) %>%
  rowid_to_column()
tbl
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   rowid start     end           val
#>   <int> <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1     1 Paris     Barcelona -0.0789
#> 2     2 Berlin    Munich    -0.502 
#> 3     3 Munich    Paris      0.132 
#> 4     4 Barcelona Rome       0.887

row_orders <- permutations(nrow(tbl)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  unite(order, remove = FALSE) %>%
  nest(-order) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, as.integer))

sample_orders <- row_orders
sample_tbl <- tbl

while (nrow(sample_orders) > 1) {
  keep_together <- sample_tbl %>%
    mutate(
      nrc = lead(start) == end,
      nrc = replace_na(nrc, FALSE),
      cumsum = cumsum(lag(nrc, default = FALSE) == FALSE)
      ) %>%
    group_by(cumsum) %>%
    summarise(row_groups = str_c(rowid, collapse = "_")) %>%
    filter(str_length(row_groups) > 1) %>%
    `[[`("row_groups")
  sample_orders <- sample_orders %>%
    filter(str_detect(order, keep_together))
  sample_tbl <- tbl %>%
    slice(sample_orders$data[[sample(1:nrow(sample_tbl), 1)]])
}
#> Error in slice_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: subscript out of bounds.
print(sample_tbl)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   rowid start     end           val
#>   <int> <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1     2 Berlin    Munich    -0.502 
#> 2     3 Munich    Paris      0.132 
#> 3     1 Paris     Barcelona -0.0789
#> 4     4 Barcelona Rome       0.887
```

Created on 2018-04-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).